# Need help revising an autocheckout script

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

a noob here. Just trying to configure a script I received from a buddy. Looking for the script to hit the submit button for me after it autofills all my info. I've been trying for a few hrs to try to do it :( but alas, I'm stuck!

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

function interva15(){
    var submitorder = document.getElementById("orderSubmit");

    submitorder.click();
      }
var id5 = interva15();
```

The website I'm trying to use the script on elements:

```
<input alt="Submit Order" src="https://www.websitename.com/checkout/ckout_submit_order.gif" type="image" id="orderSubmit" name="orderSubmit" width="150" height="28" />
```

it was to my understand that you must correlate an action with the correct element on the page to create an action? Again, I do apologize, pretty new to this.

Answer (score 1):

**in Html**

```
   <form action="desired url" type="POST" id="submitform">
    <input alt="Submit Order" src="https://www.websitename.com/checkout/ckout_submit_order.gif" type="image" id="orderSubmit" name="orderSubmit" width="150" height="28" />
    </form>
```

**in js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

function interva15(){
    var submitorder = document.getElementById("submitform");

    submitorder.submit();
      }
var id5 = interva15();
```

Comment: This is not an answer - this is a rewrite of the OP's question.

Comment: see i submit form with the form id

Answer (score 0):

1. `window.addEventListener('load', function() {` means "when the window has loaded, do whatever is in the function.
2. `var submitorder = document.getElementbyId("orderSubmit");` finds an element in the DOM that has the id, `orderSubmit` and stores it in the variable `submitorder`.
3. `submitorder.click()` calls the function that would be called when that element is clicked.